# in Unity2D, How do I detect a sprite totally hidden by other sprites?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, gameobject 'X' is not visible at all on the actual 2D camera. Is there a way to detect sprites in this situation?

Comment: Do you mea "detect" as in raycasting, or do you just mean "have the camera see it?"  The answer to your question is you must learn about the layer system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ray cating is the answer. thanks joe.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite rendering goes in this order:

1. In the SpriteRenderer component you have layers slot. This slot tells you to which render layer (not GameObject layer) your sprite belongs to. Layers control the render order of your sprites.
2. Now if 2 sprites are in the same layer than the the render order is controlled by the Z value (just below Layer slot in SpriteRenderer). The higher the value the higher the order.
3. But even if 2 sprites have the same Z value than the render order is determined by proximity to camera.

So there is no general rule of setting up sprite render order - it varies from project to project.

Comment: All true, but unfortunately it's totally unknown what OP is asking.